# adding an existing repository to svn

Tags: svn, centos7

On our server the operating system is on a HD different from the rest of the filesystem. To upgrade it from CentOS 6 to CentOS 7 i replaced the disk containing CentOS 6 wit a new disk, on which i installed CentOS 7.
So the entire filesystem, including my svn repository remained unchanged.
But in this naive setup, svn called from a workstation can not find the repository:

```
svn: E210005: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://user12@xxx.yyy.zzz/home/main_svn/QHG/branches/multi_spc'
svn: E210005: No repository found in 'svn+ssh://user12@xxx.yyy.zzz/home/main_svn/QHG/branches/multi_spc'
```

I now need to get this existing repository back under the control of svn, but i don't know how to proceed.
(the posts i found so far, only talk about creating a new repository)

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Do you still have the old disk? Could you access it, make a dump of the repository and import this in the new system?

Comment: Yes, i still have the disk. How would i have to import the dump in the new system?

Comment: I just found 'svnadmin dump' and 'svnadmin load' which should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, right track

Comment: ...and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Solution in this case was to make a dump from the repository on the still accessible old disk and import this in the new system.

Involved commands:[svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) and [svnadmin load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html)